# Remove comments including the line they are in?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am working on a quick fix to remove comments from particular syntax tree elements - it's producing the expected results in almost every case.

However I can't seem to find a way to remove comments including their leading and trailing trivia.

Neither this way:

```
var comments = syntaxRoot.DescendantTrivia().Where(trivia => trivia.IsKind(SyntaxKind.SingleLineCommentTrivia) || trivia.IsKind(SyntaxKind.MultiLineCommentTrivia));

var replaced = syntaxRoot
            .ReplaceTrivia(comments, (b, a) => SyntaxFactory.ElasticMarker);

return document.WithSyntaxRoot(replaced);
```

nor this way:

```
internal class CommentRemovalRewriter : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public CommentRemovalRewriter(bool visitIntoStructuredTrivia = false) : base(visitIntoStructuredTrivia)
    {
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public CommentRemovalRewriter(SyntaxTrivia replacementTrivia, bool visitIntoStructuredTrivia = false) : base(visitIntoStructuredTrivia)
    {
        ReplacementTrivia = replacementTrivia;
    }

    public SyntaxTrivia ReplacementTrivia { get; set; } = SyntaxFactory.ElasticMarker; 

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override SyntaxTrivia VisitTrivia(SyntaxTrivia trivia)
    {
        if(trivia.IsKind(SyntaxKind.MultiLineCommentTrivia) || trivia.IsKind(SyntaxKind.SingleLineCommentTrivia))
            return ReplacementTrivia;

        return base.VisitTrivia(trivia);
    }
}
```

works the way I want it to with array declarations (note that it does work just fine with methods, removing comments as well as leading/trailing trivia.

```
var bla = new[]
{
    // comment
    1,
    // comment
    2,
    // comment
    3,
};
```

into this

```
var bla = new[]
{

    1,

    2,

    3,
};
```

instead of this

```
var bla = new[]
{
    1,
    2,
    3,
};
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation)`?

Comment: @PauloMorgado Yes. Adds an additional linebreak and makes the result even worse sadly